# Need a simple excel formula for sum of 8 times

Tags: excel, sum

Here is what i am looking for:

I'm doing a excel sheet with 50+ items, all of them need to add a formula with a sum that assuming x equal to 1 to 8.

Here is what I'm looking for,

a sum of `30(X)(2000 - 50(X))`, assume

```
  X=1 +   
  X=2 +     
  X=3......+ X=7 + X=8.....
```

total of 8 formulas add up together.

Answer (score 0):

If your 8 values are in a single range like A1:A8 you can use this formula:

> =SUMPRODUCT(A1:A8,2000-50*A1:A8)*30